# How to start with designing graphs application for iPhone/iPad app

Tags: iphone

I am a new bee to developing iphone/ipad apps. I want to build a app which will draws graph based on some JSON parameters(Optional).

Could you guys step in and guide how do i start with building such.

Answer (score 0):

You need tree view for showing your graph. You can use some solutions, for example:

http://code.google.com/p/treeview-4iphone/

http://dotnet.kapenilattex.com/?p=656

you will take solution for storage and will draw with your custom objects

Comment: A nice approach but i am thinking how do i call an URL from app and the URL will render in app itself...Any clue